# Integrating general powers of the Mahalanobis norm with respect to spherical measure

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, spherical-coordinates

Let $S^{d-1}$ denote the $d$-dimensional sphere, and $\sigma_{d-1}$ denote the corresponding spherical measure. I am wondering how to go about solving the following integral for $c>0$

$$
\int_{S^{d-1}} \|M u\|_2^{2c} d \sigma_{d-1}(u),
$$

where $M$ is a positive definite and symmetric matrix. The obvious first step is to substitute $v=Mu$ but I am not quite sure how to work with the spherical measure, even for the simpler setting of $c=1$. In the setting where $M=I$ then $\|Mu\|= \|u\|=1$ whenever $u \in S^{d-1}$, so here we have
$$
\int_{S^{d-1}} \|M u\|_2^{2c} d \sigma_{d-1}(u)
=
\int_{S^{d-1}} \|u\|_2^{2c} d \sigma_{d-1}(u)
=
\int_{S^{d-1}} d \sigma_{d-1}(u)
= S(d)
$$

where $S(d)$ is the surface area of the $d$-dimensional sphere.

Any hints or references to relevant material for dealing with the more general setting would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Actually $v=Mu$ is the wrong way to go, as you said you don't know how to work with the spherical measure (it doesn't even preserve the sphere).

The trick is that since $M$ is symmetric and positive definite, we have an orthogonal matrix $O$ (that is, $O^T O = O O^T=I$) such that
$$
M = O^T \Lambda O,
$$
where $\Lambda = \operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_d)$ is a diagonal matrix with positive entries.

Then
$$
\|Mu\|_2^2=u^TM^TMu=u^TO^T \Lambda OO^T \Lambda Ou=(Ou)^T\Lambda^2(Ou)=\|\Lambda(Ou)\|_2^2.
$$
Now let $v=Ou$, and since $O$ is orthogonal, it is a diffeomorphism of the sphere, and $d\sigma_{d-1}(u)=d\sigma_{d-1}(v)$. We then have
$$
\int_{S^{d-1}} \|Mu\|_2^{2c}d\sigma_{d-1}(u)=\int_{S^{d-1}} \|\Lambda(Ou)\|_2^{2c}d\sigma_{d-1}(u)=\int_{S^{d-1}} \|\Lambda v\|_2^{2c}d\sigma_{d-1}(v).
$$

Now
$$
\|\Lambda v\|_2^2 = \lambda_1^2 v_1^2 + \dots + \lambda_d^2 v_d^2.
$$
This integral is easier than before. I am not too sure how to go for a real $c>0$, but if $c$ is a positive integer, we can expand $(\|\lambda v\|_2^2)^c$ out, and reduce it to a sum of the following kind of integrals.

We actually have a concrete formula
$$
\int_{S^{d-1}} v_1^{2a_1}\dots v_d^{2a_d}\, d\sigma_{d-1}(v) = \frac{2\Gamma(a_1+\frac{1}{2})\cdots \Gamma(a_d+\frac{1}{2})}{\Gamma(a_1+\cdots+a_d+\frac{d}{2})}, \quad a_i\in {\mathbb Z}_{\geq 0}.
$$
This can be standard, but let me write out the details for the proof.

Consider the spherical coordinates on ${\mathbb R}^d$ with $\rho>0$, $(v_1,\dots,v_d)\in S^{d-1}$. Then $(x_1,\dots,x_d)\in {\mathbb R}^d$ with $x_i=\rho v_i$. We have
\begin{align}
&\quad\ \big(\int_{S^{d-1}} v_1^{2a_1}\dots v_d^{2a_d}\, d\sigma_{d-1}(v)\big)\big(\int_0^\infty e^{-\rho^2} \rho^{2(a_1+\dots+a_d)+d-1}\,d\rho\big)\\
&=\int_0^\infty e^{-\rho^2} \int_{S^{d-1}} (\rho v_1)^{2a_1}\dots (\rho v_d)^{2a_d} d\sigma_{d-1}(v)\, \rho^{d-1}d\rho\\
&=\int_{{\mathbb R}^d} e^{-(x_1^2+\dots+x_d^2)}x_1^{2a_1}\dots x_d^{2a_d}\,dx\\
&=\big(\int_{\mathbb R} e^{-x_1^2}x_1^{2a_1}\,dx_1\big)\dots \big(\int_{\mathbb R} e^{-x_d^2}x_d^{2a_d}\,dx_d\big).
\end{align}
Now simple substitutions show that
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty e^{-\rho^2} \rho^{2(a_1+\dots+a_d)+d-1}\,d\rho&= \frac{1}{2}\Gamma(a_1+\dots+a_d+\frac{d}{2}),\\
\int_{\mathbb R} e^{-x_i^2}x_i^{2a_i}\,dx_i &= \Gamma(a_i+\frac{1}{2}).
\end{align}
Putting these together, we get the desired formula.

Comment: is there a good reference for the concrete formula, since you mention it is a standard result?

Comment: I don't remember where I read this, but I recorded this in my formula file, and remember such a formula exists. So I dug the formula out, and found that I can reproduce the proof. The idea for the proof is just a more sophisticated version of how you calculate the surface area of the sphere $S^{d-1}$, which is the case when all the $a_i=0$.

Comment: a little unrelated to my original question but I am wondering if the concrete formula can be generalized to nicely behaved functions. That is, if we were to replace $v_i$ with for example $e^{-v_i}$ for each $i$, can we still get a closed form solution ?

Comment: I would think unlikely. The $v_i$ on the sphere are like some trig functions, so $e^{v_i}$ would be hard to integrate. Also the proof is to multiply by the radius $\rho$ so that $\rho v_i = x_i$, this doesn't seem to generalize to other kind of functions.

Comment: On the other hand, every analytic function is expressed using such powers, so in a sense such integrals cover everything you need. For your example of $e^{v_i}$, you can do power series expansion, and integrate term by term, then you get a complicated series which should be the answer.